# what does "up" stand for in the following sentence?

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses, intransitive-preposition

**OP**:

> US GDP for the second quarter was revised sharply higher at an annualised rate of 3.7%, *up* from the first estimate of 2.3%.

In the sentence above, does it equal:

> US GDP for the second quarter was revised sharply higher at an annualised rate of 3.7%, **which is** *up* from the first estimate of 2.3%.

Answer (score 1):

By putting pronouns in such case, you simply elaborate the sentence *further*. The sentence is 'okay' without it as well.

Yes, in the sentence, 'up' means over/more than what was estimated for the previous one.

Comment: I don't get it..however. the word "up" there is an adjective,right?

Comment: Yes.  Like in "*time is **up***".